# memory usage and efficiency related to 'extended' cursors versus multiple transactions in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, indexeddb

I have an object store that has an inline key path and two indexes.  The first index identifies a portfolio, such as '2'.  The second index identifies the module under a portfolio, such as '2.3' for the 3rd module of portfolio '2'. And the key path identifies the data object within the module, such as '2.3.5'. As the user builds his or her modules, the individual objects are written to the database.

Suppose a user decides to delete an entire portfolio of large size. I'd like to understand which of two ways would be the best in terms of efficiency and memory usage for deleting all data from the object store for that specific portfolio.

One method could open a cursor on the desired portfolio index within a single transaction to delete each item in the object store having that portfolio index value.

A second method, in my particular case, is to use a pointer.  I have a pointer array that keeps track of every data object's key path in the object store.  This is because a user could choose to insert a new item at position 2 within a module of 100 items.  Rather than stepping through the store for the particular module and changing all the key paths for each item 2.3.2 through 2.3.100 to be 2.3.3 through 2.3.101, for example, I add the inserted item as 2.3.101 and place it at position 2 in the pointer, since it's much easier to update the pointer than to move large pieces of data in the database through copying them, deleting them, and writing them again with a new key path.

So, the second method could be to step through the pointer deleting all data objects by the key path stored in the pointer for that portfolio and to perform each deletion in a separate transaction.

The questions are:

1. Is it accurate that a large transaction, such as an open cursor across many data objects, requires the browser to store large amounts of data in memory in order to be able to rollback that transaction if any step fails along the way?
2. If so, is it better to employ the second approach since each transaction works on one data object only? Or, is it inefficient to repeatedly open small transactions on the same object store and search for each object by specific key path as opposed to just stepping through the store by an ordered index?
3. If the multiple-transaction approach is taken, would the browser release the memory quickly enough that there'd be a reduction in the total memory used during the entire process, or would it hold on to it until after the entire process completes such that it would accumulate to the same point anyway.

In this case, please assume the expected size of a large portfolio to be 50 modules of 100 objects each, such that the comparison is between a single transaction working on 5,000 data objects through a cursor versus performing 5,000 individual transactions on a single data object at a time through the known key path.

Perhaps, I am overthinking all of this because I am new to it and attempting to learn a bunch of things in a hurry.  Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.

Comment: did you ever figure out the best way to implement this?

Comment: @bgmaster I'm not sure if I found an answer to the particular question I asked, but what I finally employed was changing my key to an array, removing the indexes, and deleting through a key range, such as `IDBKeyRange.bound( [ k, 0 ], [ k + 1, 0 ], false, true )`, in a single transaction. This worked the best for my particular case; but I don't have a bench mark study of performance under the other methods to provide. Being a novice, I thought an array for a key would be slow or difficult but it works fine and fast and simplified much of my code.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks

Comment: @bgmaster You're welcome. I forgot about this old question also, which just deletes using the index value. I don't know if it will be useful for you but here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55927915/deleting-all-records-in-indexeddb-object-store-for-a-specific-index-value. And this unanswered question is why I went with the key range instead of an index. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60824806/indexeddb-using-an-index-versus-a-key-range

Comment: @bgmaster I apologize for I wrote that first statement incorrectly. The fact is that although all the records could be retrieved using getAll and an index, they could not all be deleted using an index because there is not a deleteAll. That is discussed in the fisrt link.